# JavaScript/JQuery select child

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a visualization in d3, and I am trying to retrieve the text value for each legend, that is, `Text 1` to `Text 4`. How can I select the `<text>` under `<g>` in either `JavaScript`, `JQuery` or `d3`? I have done `$(".legend").children()` or `$(".legend")[0]`, but I can't continue further.

```
<g class=​"legend" transform=​"translate(0,0)​">​
    <rect x=​"100" y=​"-12" width=​"18" height=​"18" fill=​"#1f77b4">​</rect>​
    <text x=​"120" y=​"0" style=​"text-anchor:​ start;​">Text 1​</text>​
</g>​
<g class=​"legend" transform=​"translate(0,20)​">​
    <rect x=​"100" y=​"-12" width=​"18" height=​"18" fill=​"#ff7f0e">​</rect>​
    <text x=​"120" y=​"0" style=​"text-anchor:​ start;​">Text 2</text>​
</g>​
<g class=​"legend" transform=​"translate(0,40)​">​
    <rect x=​"100" y=​"-12" width=​"18" height=​"18" fill=​"#2ca02c">​</rect>​
    <text x=​"120" y=​"0" style=​"text-anchor:​ start;​">Text 3​</text>​
</g>​
<g class=​"legend" transform=​"translate(0,60)​">​
    <rect x=​"100" y=​"-12" width=​"18" height=​"18" fill=​"#d62728">​</rect>​
    <text x=​"120" y=​"0" style=​"text-anchor:​ start;​">Text 4​</text>​
</g>​
```

Comment: `d3.selectAll('.legend text')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for this..

```
    $.each($('.legend text'),function(){
      //console.log($(this).text());
       alert($(this).text());
   })
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K62Vr/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('.legend text')` should obtain all your items. Then I'm not sure if you'll need `.html()` or `.text()` for SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector:

```
$('g text')
```

to iterate over them one by one, you need `.each()`:

```
$('g text').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```